# how can I redirect login page if do not login in yii framework?

Tags: yii

I have the actionLogin and create cookie like here :

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = 'login';

        $model=new LoginForm;

        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {           
            $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            if($model->validate() && $model->login()){          
                $cookie = new CHttpCookie('loginSuccess',$model->username);
                $cookie->expire = 604800;                   
                Yii::app()->request->cookies['loginSuccess'] = $cookie;         
                $this->redirect('/ktbeauty/index.php/categories/index');
            }           
        }

        $this->render('login',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

And Now I have some controllers which must check to login before access controllers, if not login, it must redirect to login page, how can I work for this ?

thankyou very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the action of your controller you can try something like this

```
public function actionGoToLogin()
{
if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            {
             // do something if user is authenticated   
            }
            else
            {
                Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
              // or if you want you can redirect using Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/login');
            }
}
```

Comment: @Let how can the code above be used for all the controllers? because the code above will be used repeatedly> I just want to use the code at once.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, you have a function as below:

```
public function accessRules() {
```

Here you can define the actions and users who can access those functions.
If you are not logged in, then it'll redirected to login page by default.

This feature available by default in YII.

check this URL:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/169/configuring-controller-access-rules-to-default-deny/